# get property using linq

Tags: c#, linq

this might be really simple, but just need some help in getting the syntax right! 
let's say i have 2 classes A, B.

```
class A 
{
    string empname;
    string id;
    Child[] ca;
}

class Child
{
    string id;
    string name;
}

class B 
{
    string empname;
    string id;
    Child[] cb;
}
```

i want to map ca.name to cb.name. condition is cb.id= ca.id. how to do this in linq? i tried the below way:

```
ca.name=b.Child.select(x=>x.id.Equals(ca.id)) //here how to map the name property?
```

Comment: What's the relevance of your `Child` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean when you say map?  You want the name where the property are equal?  Your classes seem to be a bit off in terms of access specification from your example, and from your example not sure if your array name is really cb or Child, I'll assume Child, but correct as necessary...

Basically there are several choices:

- `Single()` - returns one and only one and throws if none or multiple.
- `SingleOrDefault()` - returns one if exists, default if not, and throws if multiple
- `First()` - returns first one if exists and throws if not.
- `FirstOrDefault()` - returns first one if exists, default if not.

All of these have a predicate overload so you don't need a where clause.  If you already know your item is unique, I'd recommend `FirstOrDefault()` since it stops after it finds it, whereas `Single()` has to scan the whole list, which could get a bit more expensive.

```
var item = b.Child.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == ca.id);

if (item != null)
{
  ca.name = item.name;
}
```

Or you can use a where/select combo with null coalescing:

```
var name = b.Child.Where(x => x.id == ca.id)
       .Select(x => x.name)
       .FirstOrDefault() ?? "unknown";
```

Comment: Where() gets you a range, if you want the first match (or default (null for classes) if no match) use FirstOrDefault()

Comment: how can i do even the null check in one statement?                 Also, var name = b.Child.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == ca.id); returns the object b and we can't do ca.name = name;

Comment: Corrected the flaw, you're right it does return the item, not the name.  You can either return the whole item w FirstOrDefault() -- uses less chaining -- or you can use Where/Select/First combo to narrow right down to the name

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `Where` instead of `Select`

Comment: I'd recommend FirstOrDefault() over where since where gives you a range instead of the first (hopefully only) match

Comment: It's true, but I can see from the question that asker is still in the early phase: mistaking 'Select' for the SQL keyword, essentially. He will probably expect a list result (like in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it this way:

```
var query = from innerItem in cb.cb
            where item.id.Equals(item.id)
            select innerItem;

if (query != null)
{
    item.name = query.Single().name;
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, unless I'm misunderstanding your question, the answer is pretty trivial:

```
     ca.name=b.Child.Where(x=>x.id.Equals(ca.id)).SingleOrDefault().Name;
```

Comment: Can eliminate Where with FirstOrDefault overload that takes a predicate

Comment: `.SingleOrDefault().Name` doesn't make much sense. If you think there might not be a matching item, then you should check to make sure SingleOrDefault didn't return null before trying to read the Name property. If you know there will always be a matching item, you should use Single instead.

Comment: +1 don't assume finds it.  Either handle exception from Single() or check for null or use null-coalescing ?? operator

Answer (score 0):

Use [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) clause:

```
var pairs=
    from a in ca    
    join b in cb on a.id equals b.id
    select new {a, b};
```